# Copy select option ID value into hidden field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, forms

I've seen a few tutorials where you can copy the value of a select option into a hidden field like this:

```
$("#my_stuff").change(function(){
    $("#my_hidden_field").val($("select option:selected").val());
});
```

So if I had this...

```
<select name="my_stuff" id="my_stuff">
    <option value="Red">Red things</option>
    <option value="Green">Green things</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue things</option>
</select>
```

...and selected 'Red things', then 'Red things' would be copied into the hidden field value.

**But what I really need to do** is copy the **ID** instead, so if I had this...

```
<select name="my_stuff" id="my_stuff">
    <option value="Red" id="all the red stuff">Red things</option>
    <option value="Green" id="all the green stuff">Green things</option>
    <option value="Blue" id="all the blue stuff">Blue things</option>
</select>
```

...and I selected 'Red things', then 'all the red stuff' would be copied into the hidden field.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple:
Here you go:

```
$("#my_stuff").change(function(){
    $("#my_hidden_field").val($("select option:selected").attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Perfect - target the attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @user3256143 for voting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get **id** instead of **value** then add `.attr('id')` instead of `.val()`

```
$("#my_stuff").change(function(){
    $("#my_hidden_field").val($("select option:selected").attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

```
$("#my_stuff").change(function(){
    $("#my_hidden_field").val($(this).children(":selected").attr('id'));
});
```

Note also that you're losing the relationship between the `select` that fired the event, and the `select` you're interrogating to get the chosen value. Change:

```
$("select option:selected") //any select, not necessarily the event trigger
```

to

```
$(this).children(":selected") //specifically, the select that triggered the event
```

Note also that, in the first example, you don't have to drill down to the selected `option` and get *its* value; jQuery is clever enough that, if you simply ask for `.val()` on the `select` itself, it does this for you.

```
$("#my_stuff").change(function(){
    $("#my_hidden_field").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Altertaniteva way:

```
$("#my_stuff").change(function(){
   $("#my_hidden_field").val($("select option:selected").prop('id'));
});
```