# Post unselected option from multiple select in form php

Tags: php, html, jquery

I can get my selectedFruit array in PHP, but how to fill the hidden input using js or jquery so I can do my objective?

```
<form id="my_form" action method="post">
<select name="selectedFruit[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Grape</option>
    <option value="3">Apple</option>
    <option value="4">Watermelon</option>
</select>
<input hidden name="unselectedFruit[]">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

my objective is to do this in my php file:

```
$selected_array_fruit = $_POST["selectedFruit[]"];
$unselected_array_fruit = $_POST["unselectedFruit[]"];
```

Comment: I know it can be hard to come up with the right search terms, but please do try searching before posting a new question. I tried "copy selected value to hidden field" and turned up plenty of answers here with code you can copy.  This one even has it in the question, not the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153197/copy-select-option-id-value-into-hidden-field-with-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy select option ID value into hidden field with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153197/copy-select-option-id-value-into-hidden-field-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new input values if selection is changed.

 - Create function which filter unselected values from select and create new hidden inputs with unselectedFruit[] name for PHP array.
 - Create listener for change and recalculate select options.

```
// this is for explain and by default is truncated and filtered by selector
// option:selected and remove the line 'skip selected'
const loadSelectUncheckedValues = function() {
  $('[name="unselectedFruit[]"]').remove(); // clean all
  $('select[name="selectedFruit[]"] option').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':selected')) return; // skip selected
    $('#my_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="unselectedFruit[]" value="'+$(this).val()+'" />');
  });
}

// init
loadSelectUncheckedValues();

$('select[name="selectedFruit[]"]').on('change', function() {
    loadSelectUncheckedValues();
});
```

Comment: Curious why you need to remove the hidden input then insert a new one

Comment: @charlietfl this is because 'unselectedFruit' inputs are generated only from js and not exist in document. I think better/easy is refresh them all then check differences. IMHO. The key is not in js but create new array values for php. I think this is what OP wants.